# Disable link after click until the page loads

Tags: javascript, html

I am using Flask to make a webapp. The reset href triggers the method I showed below the html code. That method runs a bash script via OS.system python module and it needs time to run. During that script running time, my page is loading and I can click multiple times on the reset link, triggering the method each time and therefore the bash script.

HTML:
`<a href="/reset" onclick="clickAndDisable(this);"> <div class="butonulmeu"> <span>RESET</span> <br> <img src="/static/images/reset.png"> </div> </a>`

Python Flask method:

```
   @app.route('/reset')
   def Reset():
   
       system("./bash_script.sh")
       return redirect('/')
```

I tried to disable the link after one click using this java script code, however, it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <script> 
              function clickAndDisable(link) {
              // disable subsequent clicks
              link.onclick = function(event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
              }
            }   
         </script>
    <a href="/reset" onclick="clickAndDisable(this);">
            <div class="butonulmeu">
                <span>RESET</span> <br>
                <img src="/static/images/reset.png">
            </div>
        </a>
```

Comment: When the link is clicked, the browser navigates to `/reset`, which then redirects the user back to `/`. Every navigation resets all of the JavaScript state, so the link is always in its initial state.

Comment: You'll probably want to create an API on your server which the client page can use to somehow determine the status of the action. There are many ways to accomplish this, and the most suitable one will depend on the details of your server application.

Answer (score 0):

When a visitor goes to a URL from a link, javascript variables will be reset. So there will be no reference to the fact that the link was clicked. There are a few solutions to this, my solution is using localstorage to show that the link was clicked before.

This code will detect if reset was saved to local storage. If it wasn't, save it to local storage and allow the click by not doing anything. If it has been saved, prevent the default clicking of the link.

```
function clickAndDisable(link) {
   if(!localStorage.getItem("reset")){
       localStorage.setItem("reset",1);
   }
   else{
     event.preventDefault();
   }
}


<a href="/reset" onclick="clickAndDisable(this);">
  <div class="butonulmeu">
    <span>RESET</span> <br>
    <img src="/static/images/reset.png">
  </div>
</a>
```